# Migrating to local server

Tags: wordpress, migration, localhost

I have my wordpress site on my local server at the following path :

```
wordpress-4.2.3\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme
```

and the url to access my local site is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress/
```

Now I need to migrate it to another local server, for this I have imported database successfully and copied `wordpress` folder and placed it in my project's folder as below:

```
my-project-name\wp-content\themes\mytheme
```

and also changed `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`  which is initially `http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress/` to `http://local-server-ip/my-project-name/` but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace **all** URLs in the database, it is not sufficient to change the values only in the options table (otherwise links and images are corrupted).

**Manual Migration**:

1. Export your database (e.g. through phpMyAdmin) and do a search&replace with the old and new url
2. Update your **wp-config.php** (database name, login and passwort)
3. Update your **.htaccess** file (check the **RewriteBase** and **Rewrite Rule**)

**Migration with Plugin:**
Download a migration plugin, such as "Wordpress Duplicator"

Comment: I have completed with first two steps before, now from `.htaccess` file  I have updated `RewriteRule` and `RewriteBase` too. But on my site it is only display main menu and footer. No `index.php` content

Comment: Did you copy the **whole** wordpress folder to the new location? Besides the steps described above, nothing else needs to be done. Otherwise you can still use a plugin for migration, it's much faster. Please also list the content of your .htaccess file.

Comment: yes I have copied the whole wordpress folder and paste it into my `project` folder

Comment: You must have miss some URL in your database. Check on `siteurl` and `home` values in `wp_options`. If they're correctly set then you have something wrong in your htaccess. And be more explicit than "it is not working" > you get redirected to a wrong url, you get a PHP error, or a 404...?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all data to folder "my-project-name"

Open your database > click on SQL tab > Run these commands manually

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WP Update Query in database
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress', 'http://local-server-ip/my-project-name') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';


UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress', 'http://local-server-ip/my-project-name');


UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress', 'http://local-server-ip/my-project-name');


UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://localhost/wordpress-4.2.3/wordpress','src="http://local-server-ip/my-project-name');
```

then login to your wordpress admin panel go to Setting > Permalinks > click on Save Changes button.

Note: if you have changed your database don't forget to change credintials in wp-config.php